# VEEAM Linux Agent: Detect partition tables. Failed

Tags: linux, debian, proxmox

I use the VEEAM agent version 6.0.3.1221 with Debian 12.1 (PROXMOX). At first everything worked fine for weeks. Suddenly we have the following issue - see the log. Is it possible to disable the partition check? I guess it has a problem with some specific virtual disks of PROXMOX.

Log:

```
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> lsm | Probing partition table on [/dev/zd256].
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> lsm | Partition table type (on: /dev/zd256): [dos].
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> dsk | Async read mode is [true]
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> dsk | I/O statistics for '/dev/zd256': 512 bytes read unaligned (1 requests)
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> lsm | Objects relationship: link child [PartitionTable] 'dos 90909090' <-> parent [BlockDevice] '/dev/zd256' single flag: '1'.
[ 16:24:37.478] <140405542733504> lpbdevenu| Try get partition from blkid for device [/dev/zd256p1].
[ 16:24:37.479] <140405542733504> lpbdevenu| Try get partition from blkid for device [/dev/zd256p5].[ 16:24:37.479] <140405542733504> lpbdevenu| Try get partition from blkid for device [/dev/zd256p6].
[ 16:24:37.480] <140405542733504> lsm | Partition [/dev/zd256p1]. Offset: [32256]. Size: [16105065984]. Index: [1].
[ 16:24:37.480] <140405542733504> lsm | Objects relationship: link child [Partition] 'part 1' <-> parent [PartitionTable] 'dos 90909090' single flag: '1'.
[ 16:24:37.480] <140405542733504> lsm | Objects relationship: link child [BlockDevice] '/dev/zd256p1' <-> parent [Partition] 'part 1' single flag: '1'.
[ 16:24:37.480] <140405542733504> lsm | Probing partition table on [/dev/zd256]. Failed.
[ 16:24:37.480] <140405542733504> lsm | Detect partition tables. Failed.
```

I tried to reinstall the VEEAM Agent. I tried to find a configuration to skip partition detection while starting the agent.

Comment: Is this a file-level or a volume-level backup? Does the device `/dev/zd256` actually contain a DOS MBR partition table (with three partitions: `p1`, `p5` and `p6`), or is that a misdetection? If so, what does the device actually contain? Is it partitioned using a GPT partition table, or has it been initialized as a single whole-disk filesystem, or does it contain a LVM volume or something more complicated?

Comment: It is a volume-level backup. The partition table of the affected disk looks as following:

`zd256                                                                                                    
├─zd256p1   ext4        1.0                        cf...                  
├─zd256p2                                                                                                
└─zd256p5   swap        1                          9c...`

They are virtual disks of a PROXMOX system. `p6` is a misdetection instead of `p2`. In this virtual disk we have a DOS MBR partition. No LVM or any others.